# Undefined function 'myfun' for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: matlab

This error is driving me crazy! I've spent 3 hours searching for what the cause might be and how to fix it but to no avail. I simply want to use `fsolve` to solve a  non linear system of equations. Here is what I've done:

Creating a function file named `myfun.m` :

```
function F = myfun(x)
F = [x(1)*x(2)+exp(x(1))+x(1)-3;
     x*sin(x)+(x(2))^2-2];
end
```

Call upon my function to compute the roots :

```
x0 = [0,0];
fsolve(@myfun,x0)
```

Yes, I have saved the functionfile with a name "myfun" in the exact same path as the rest of my Matlab files.

For this method, I followd this guy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WPVuyJ3uHhE

It works perfectly for him but not for me. Does anyone what causes my error? Here follows the whole error message :

```
Undefined function 'myfun' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in fsolve (line 230)
            fuser = feval(funfcn{3},x,varargin{:});

Error in Bonus_a (line 14)
fsolve(@myfun,x0)

Caused by:
    Failure in initial objective function evaluation. FSOLVE cannot continue.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your second equation is incorrect because you mix `x` as vector and `x` as scalar. The corrected code would be something like this:

```
function F = myfun(x)
if nargin<1,
    x=[0;0]
end
F = [x(1)*x(2)+exp(x(1))+x(1)-3;
     x(1)*sin(x(2))+(x(2))^2-2]
end
```

The first three lines after the function definition is useful addition to test your function without the need to call it from other functions. Running this function alone will give you results such as

```
ans =

         -2.00
         -2.00
```

Now you can use the optimization:

```
x0 = [0,0];
fsolve(@myfun,x0)
```

This will produce results without error:

```
ans =

          0.56          1.21
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I still get the same error message. I think there is another problem here. I've copied what you wrote.

Comment: Did you try the code I am putting above? Simply copy and paste the code  above and run will produce no error.

Comment: I did exactly as you suggested. I did copy and paste it. That's why I thought the error might be caused by something else?

Comment: I got it! The path was not set at all. I had it set a few months ago but after getting a new PC it vanished. Tanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I see two problems here. The first one is that the exception this code should actually produce is not:

> Undefined function 'myfun' for input arguments of type 'double'.

but:

> Error using *
>
> Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

So, unless you are using a Matlab version different from mine (2017a) and consistent changes have been made on the inner data validation code of `fsolve`... I think there is a mismatch between the code you posted and the code you are actually running.

Anyway, the problem arises from the fact that you are trying to solve a system of equations with two uknowns but the code in your function is a mix between a vectorized calculation and an indexed calculation with errors in between (if you want to perform an element wise multiplication between two vectors, you must use the `.*` operator instead of `*`, the same goes for `^` and so on). Once every computation has been performed, the output argument `F` of `myfun` must contain no less and no more than `2` elements.

Basically, the second equation must be changed so that it returns a single scalar, for example like this (it's up to you to choose the proper offsets `1` and `2` of `x` in the second equation, since you didn't provide the original formulation of your problem):

```
function F = myfun(x)
    F = [
      x(1)*x(2)+exp(x(1))+x(1)-3;
      x(1)*sin(x(1))+(x(2))^2-2
    ];
end
```

If you run the code with the above function, it will output the following without errors:

```
ans =
      1.10175749069473          -1.0085776227304
```

Comment: I just copied and pasted your function, I still get the same error. Can the problem lie elsewhere?

Comment: I got it! The path was not set at all. I had it set a few months ago but after getting a new PC it vanished. Tanks a lot for your help!

Comment: So say I want the 4 roots closest to the origin and I know the bounds of x and y in which the roots are within, how can I only get the 4 roots? Because now I only get 2 roots.

Comment: You have to define your systems over 4 variables and make your initial guess a 4 elements vector too, if I understood properly.